# Get Weighted Rating Regarding Number of Votes Within 2 Tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

**Rooms:** id

**Visits:** rid, rating

I want to get the weight rating (where rating > 0) for each room.

Rating goes from 1 to 10. Rating 0 = User didn't rate the room, so don't count it.

How can I get that?

Thanks!

Comment: With an [inner join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp), a [where](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) clause and an [aggregator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) (probably an average (AVG) in your case.

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT
   rooms.id,
   t1.count
FROM
rooms
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT
       rid,
       COUNT(rating) as count
    FROM
       visits
    WHERE visits.rating <> 0
    GROUP BY visits.rid
) AS t1 ON rooms.id = t1.rid
```

Comment: How can the query include non-rated rooms too? It shows only rooms with 1+ votes, can I show also those with 0 votes?

Comment: just remove WHERE visits.rating <> 0 :) @D.Yeffet